# Filter MYSQL results on wildcard JOINS

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am trying to filter a table with joins to 3 different tables where one connection has a wild card as part of the join criteria. This is causing the result to output extra/unwanted rows. I can't work out how to get rid of these.

The equipment comprises of Chassis with either 1 or 2 supervisor cards. Each supervisor card has its own IP address.
If the the Chassis only has one supervisor card installed it is referenced as:
01-xxxx:N:xxxx <-N in this position

If it has 2 supervisor cards it is referenced as:

01-xxxx:P:xxxx  <-P for primary

01-xxxx:S:xxxx  <-S for secondary

The connection table comprises of Source and Destination chassis. 
This is describing the connections between chassis only. Each chassis is described only by either 01-xxxx:N:xxxx or the primary switch controller 01-xxxx:P:xxxx. There are two 'paths' an EAST (E) and WEST (W) for each Source and Destination.

I am trying to get the IP addresses of  01-xxxx:P:xxxx  and
01-xxxx:S:xxxx  from the 'equipment' table where the 'connections' table 
only references primary devices 01-xxxx:P:xxxx and then get a VLAN ID from a third table based on whether the IP address from the 'equipment' table is within an IP range and correctly display each row with: 
East Source and destination + East IP and EAST VLAN (based on IP within a range)
and
WEST Source and destination + WEST IP and WEST VLAN (based on IP within a range) (if it exists)
A sample equipment table:

```
   `equipment` (`id`, `site_code`, `site_id`, `system_name`, `ip_add`, `mcast`, `sys_loc`, `systype`, `itamname`, `dimetis`, `DNS`) VALUES
(686, '25A2', 'TAS:BAUS:MTWEL', '01-25A2:P:TAS:BAUS:MT_WELINGTON', 172525962, 4013364224, 'ACLE RD,  PRK', 6, '01-25a2-p-tas-baus-mt-welington', 0, 1),
(687, '25A2', 'TAS:BAUS:MTWEL', '01-25A2:S:TAS:BAUS:MT_WELINGTON', 172526090, 4013364224, 'ACLE RD,  PRK', 6, '01-25a2-s-tas-baus-mt-welington', 0, 1);
```

The conenctions table:

```
`connections` (`id`, `system_name_source`, `port_type`, `slot_source`, `port_source`, `system_name_dest`, `slot_dest`, `port_dest`, `cable`, `side_name`, `side`, `status`) VALUES
(332, '01-54A1:P:TAS:TLS:BATHURST', '1G Tunk', '10', '01', '01-25A2:P:TAS:BAUS:MT_WELINGTON', '12', '01', 'D 25A2 54A1 DD001', '01-54A2:P:TAS:TLS:DAVEY', 'W', 1),
(343, '01-54A2:P:TAS:TLS:DAVEY', '1G Tunk', '10', '01', '01-25A2:P:TAS:BAUS:MT_WELINGTON', '11', '01', 'D 25A2 54A2 DD001', '01-54A1:P:TAS:TLS:BATHURST', 'E', 1);
```

VLAN / IP Range table:

```
    `vlan_agg` (`id`, `vl_system_name`, `vlan_id`, `ip_sub`, `bcast`, `cidr`) VALUES
(40, '01-54A2:P:TAS:TLS:DAVEY', 72, 172525952, 172526079, 25),
(41, '01-54A1:P:TAS:TLS:BATHURST', 73, 172526080, 172526207, 25);
```

My query:

```
  SELECT 

connections.system_name_dest,
connections.side,
tgt.system_name AS system_name,
tgt.ip_add AS dest_ip,
dvlan.vlan_id AS d_vlan_id

FROM connections 
LEFT JOIN equipment tgt on SUBSTRING(tgt.system_name,1,8) like SUBSTRING(connections.system_name_dest,1,8)
LEFT JOIN vlan_agg dvlan on tgt.ip_add BETWEEN dvlan.ip_sub AND dvlan.bcast

where system_name_dest='01-25A2:P:TAS:BAUS:MT_WELINGTON'
Order By side
```

This produces four rows with 2 having incorrect destination IP addresses and VLANS:

```
Array ( [system_name_dest] => 01-25A2:P:TAS:BAUS:MT_WELINGTON [side] => E [system_name] => 01-25A2:S:TAS:BAUS:MT_WELINGTON [dest_ip] => 172526090 [d_vlan_id] => 73 ) 
Array ( [system_name_dest] => 01-25A2:P:TAS:BAUS:MT_WELINGTON [side] => E [system_name] => 01-25A2:P:TAS:BAUS:MT_WELINGTON [dest_ip] => 172525962 [d_vlan_id] => 72 ) 
Array ( [system_name_dest] => 01-25A2:P:TAS:BAUS:MT_WELINGTON [side] => W [system_name] => 01-25A2:P:TAS:BAUS:MT_WELINGTON [dest_ip] => 172525962 [d_vlan_id] => 72 ) 
Array ( [system_name_dest] => 01-25A2:P:TAS:BAUS:MT_WELINGTON [side] => W [system_name] => 01-25A2:S:TAS:BAUS:MT_WELINGTON [dest_ip] => 172526090 [d_vlan_id] => 73 )
```

The correct output should be having East IP address and East VLAN based on Primary card and West IP and West Vlan based on Secondary card in equipment table:

```
Array ( [system_name_dest] => 01-25A2:P:TAS:BAUS:MT_WELINGTON [side] => E [system_name] => 01-25A2:S:TAS:BAUS:MT_WELINGTON [dest_ip] => 172526090 [d_vlan_id] => 73 )
Array ( [system_name_dest] => 01-25A2:P:TAS:BAUS:MT_WELINGTON [side] => W [system_name] => 01-25A2:S:TAS:BAUS:MT_WELINGTON [dest_ip] => 172526090 [d_vlan_id] => 73 )
```

Any help would be appreciated. I have been struggling with this for days.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to get. But your `LEFT JOIN equipment tgt on SUBSTRING(tgt.system_name,1,8) like SUBSTRING(connections.system_name_dest,1,8)` will of course give you 4 rows (and they will not get less anymore), because both of your connection have the same value for `SUBSTRING(connections.system_name_dest,1,8)`, and both of your equipments have the same value for `SUBSTRING(tgt.system_name,1,8)` (all are `01-25A2:`). This will give you 2 times 2 = 4 rows. As I said, I don't know exactly what you are trying to join, but you probably missed a condition there (or 8->9?)

Comment: Hi Solarflare, Thanks for your response. I understand that all are 01-25A2:and why I am getting 4 rows. I can't figure out how to get the 2 rows that I want. The problem is the 'connections' table ONLY has 01-25A2:**P** but the 'equipment' table I am joining to has 01-25A2:**P** and 01-25A2:**S**. The equipment table has the data needed to then join to the 'VLAN' table to get VLAN Id's.

I am looking for a method to get the IP and VLAN for East and West sides as well as the other row data.

Comment: I unfortunately still don't understand your datamodel or your explanations, so let's try it a different way: a) Without the joins to `vlan_agg`, would your datamodel give 4 or 2 results from your `join` to `tgt` and `src`? Or can you e.g. already use `side` to get the correct rows? You can then fix the `on` condition. b) From your 4-row resultset, can you tell me which rows are not correct just from the values in the row (even if you don't display them, as long as they are in the table and would be in the row with `select *`), not by looking at the other 3 rows? You can then use a `where`.

Comment: Hi Solarflare, Thanks for taking the time to look.
I have updated my query and removed fields that are not required and added equipment.system_name field.
With a) VLAN data removed - I stll get 4 rows.

Answer (score 0):

The extra field, I added has given enough info to develop a filter that works.
(Thanks @solarflare - his questions triggered a solution)

Query now looks like:

```
    SELECT 

connections.system_name_dest,
connections.side,
tgt.system_name AS system_name,
tgt.ip_add AS dest_ip,
dvlan.vlan_id AS d_vlan_id

FROM connections 
LEFT JOIN equipment tgt on SUBSTRING(tgt.system_name,1,8) like SUBSTRING(connections.system_name_dest,1,8)
LEFT JOIN vlan_agg dvlan on tgt.ip_add BETWEEN dvlan.ip_sub AND dvlan.bcast

where system_name_dest='01-25A2:P:TAS:BAUS:MT_WELINGTON' and ((system_name NOT LIKE '%:S:%' and side = 'E') OR (system_name LIKE '%:S:%' and side = 'W') )
Order By side
```